# missed X-Spam- headers for all messages in exim4 + spamassassin

Tags: debian, email, exim

I'm trying to configure spam filter on VPS Debian Squeeze, exim4-heavy + `spamassassin` and `dovecot`.

Exim version 4.72, SpamAssassin version 3.3.1, Perl version 5.10.1

And I have an irritating problem with spamassassin: messages has no `X-Spam` headers.

Exim4 config:

```
### main/02_exim4-config_options
spamd_address = 127.0.0.1 783

### acl/40_exim4-config_check_data
warn  spam = nobody:true
   add_header = X-Spam-Score: $spam_score

accept
```

`/etc/spamassassin/local.cf` ( defaults omitted )

```
report_contact hostmaster@domain.name

add_header spam Flag _YESNOCAPS_
add_header all Status _YESNO_, score=_SCORE_ required=_REQD_ tests=_TESTS_ autolearn=_AUTOLEARN_ version=_VERSION_
add_header all Level _STARS(*)_

required_score 4.5
```

All messages have `X-Spam-Score` header added by exim, but no one has `X-Spam-` headers which should be added by `spamd`.

I have received some spam email and tried gtube.txt, but no additional headers was added

Headers of the spam ( score greater than 4.5, but no `X-Spam-Flag` )

```
X-Priority: 3
X-MSMail-Priority: Normal
X-Mailer: Microsoft Windows Live Mail 14.0.8117.416
X-MimeOLE: Produced By Microsoft MimeOLE V14.0.8117.416
X-Spam-Score: 8.8
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem you are facing is, that things work a little bit differently than how you expect them to run.

this is *not* how it works:

- <strike>exim receives an email</strike>
- <strike>exim passes the email to spamd</strike>
- <strike>spamd checks the email for spam and adds necessary headers</strike>
- <strike>spamd passes the (modified) email back to exim</strike>
- <strike>exim delivers the email</strike>

instead it works like this:

- exim reveices an email
- exim passes the email to spamd
- spamd checks the email for spam
- spamd reports the spam-status back to exim (*not* the email)
- exim does whatever it deems appropriate to the email (add some headers, discard it, ignore the results of spamd)
- exim delivers the email

luckily exim can add quite a few things to the email, based on what spamd reports.
e.g. i use:

```
warn       message = X-Spam-Score: $spam_score
  spam = nobody:true
warn       message = X-Spam-Level: $spam_bar
  spam = nobody:true
warn       message = X-Spam-Tests: $spam_report
  spam = nobody:true
```

which will add something like the following to the email-headers:

```
X-Spam-Score: 8.9
X-Spam-Level: ++++++++
X-Spam-Tests: DEAR_FRIEND=2.604,FREEMAIL_REPLYTO=1,FREEMAIL_REPLYTO_END_DIGIT=0.25,LOTS_OF_MONEY=0.001,MONEY_FRAUD_3=3.699,RCVD_IN_BL_SPAMCOP_NET=1.246,...
```

a little bit of information can be found [here](https://wiki.debian.org/Exim#Spam_scanning)

the reason for your confusion is, that spamd could *also* modify the email by itself (e.g. this is used when you run spamd after exim).
it's only that `exim-damon-heavy` handles it the way i described it.

Comment: Thanks, umläute. I have already understood how it works.